# Reallocating my Memory doesnt work properly but i dont know what im doing wrong. Any idea?

Tags: c, realloc

**code:** (at //right here is the line that doesnt work)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void insert(int size, char *arr);

void swap(char *arr, int pos1, int pos2);

void printList(int size, char *arr);

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Put in size of the list (Range[1;2^16-1]): ");
        scanf(" %d", &size);
        if (size < 0)
            printf("Put in a correct length!\n");
    } while (size <= 0);
    printf("Put in ur List: ");
    char buffer[size];
    int errFlag;
    do
    {
        errFlag = 1;
        while (fgets(buffer, size + 2, stdin))
        {
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (!isdigit(buffer[i]))
                errFlag = 0;
        if (errFlag == 0)
            printf("Input failed try again:");
    } while (errFlag == 0);
    char *list = malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(list, buffer);
    insert(size, list);
    printList(size, list);
    int input = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nDo u want to add another element(0) or a list(1)? If u want to stop type (2): ");
        scanf(" %d", &input);
        if (input != 0 && input != 1 && input != 2)
            printf("\nInput failed try again: ");
        else if (input == 1)
        {
            int tempElem = 0;
            printf("Input ur element: ");
            scanf(" %d", &tempElem);
            size++;
            printf("%d", tempElem);
            list = (char *)realloc(list, size + 1); //right here 
            list[size-1]=tempElem;
            printf("New ");
            insert(size, list);
            printList(size, list);
        }
    } while (input != 0);
    return 0;
}

void insert(int size, char *arr)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                swap(arr, j, j + 1);
            else
                j = 0;
}

void swap(char *arr, int pos1, int pos2)
{
    char temp = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = temp;
}

void printList(int size, char *arr)
{
    printf("ArrayList: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("[");
        printf("%d", arr[i]-48);
        printf("] ");
    }
}
```

My code works properly until the reallocation, but i dont get an error. The programm just stops (VScode). I did some research but didnt find any solution.

**Output:**

```
Put in size of the list (Range[1;2^16-1]): 3
Put in ur List: 123
^Z (my input to stop f gets)
ArrayList: [1] [2] [3]
Do u want to add another element(0) or a list(1)? If u want to stop type (2): 1
Input ur element: 3
3
```

Then it stops. Normally i would expect: New ArrayList: [1] [2] [3] [4]

Comment: This while loop         while (fgets(buffer, size + 2, stdin))
        {
        } does not make sense.

Comment: For the most part, your outputs do not end with newlines.  The standard output is (line) buffered by default, so that may result in the output not being presented to you immediately.  Add an `fflush(stdout);` after each such output to ensure that it is sent to the output device right away.  Also, I'm guessing that you are running this in an IDE.  Many IDEs' I/O windows exhibit strange behavior around buffering.  Prefer to run your program directly from the command line, instead.